# ImageView not collapsing with Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

In my `ProfileFragment.java` I have a collapsing toolbar.

There is a problem when I scroll the toolbar; my profile image doesn't scroll entirely.

Does the collapsing toolbar need to be inside a `Coordinator Layout`?

I've tested with relative and I couldn't scroll.

This is a gif showing its behavior:

[image: gif showing its behavior].

**This is my XML code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparabackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="203dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFotoCapa"
            android:layout_width="446dp"
            android:layout_height="203dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="-32dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner_profile"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparabackground"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/black" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: you can not user imageview after AppBarLayout, must be scrollview, RecyclerView, or viewPager there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside your `ImageView`